# Windows Form and WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf

I looked around and didn't find exactly what I'm looking for.

I have a windows form and a wcf service in the same project and I host the wcf service withing the form by doing the following:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
host.Open();

Application.Run(new Form1());
host.Close();
```

And the application which uses the service has no issues calling it.

My issue is now calling the wcf service's methods within the Windows Form. I could simply do

```
Service1 service = new Service1();
service.doWork();
```

But by doing this I'm not using the same instance as the clients of the Service (even if I use InstanceMode.Single) and I want to.

I know I could simply implement the windows form as a GUI Client of the web service (adding a service reference).

But I simply want to have the wcf service hosted in the windows form and access the same service instance as the wcf clients. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only makes sense to "get the same instance of the clients" if you are using InstanceMode.Single, so that would be mandatory. If you are doing this, you can use the `ServiceHost.SingletonInstance` property. This gives you the instance (of type Object so you will have to cast it).

I think to make this work, you have to instantiate your ServiceHost with an *instance* of `Service1` rather than with the type.

See this for details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487.aspx

In which case, you could just keep hold of a reference to the instance that you use to create the `ServiceHost`, rather than the `ServiceHost` itself, saving you the extra call to `ServiceHost.SingletonInstance`...

Comment: So I would just need to do something like:
Service1 service = (Service1)host.SingletonInstance;
service.DoWork();

Comment: Yes you can. Or, as I said, if you are manually instantiating an object in order to use the constructor I mentioned, you might as well just keep that available rather than have to go through the host. Does that make sense?